# Neo4j Cypher - Compare property values if they exist?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a large graph in which there are nodes representing people.  All of them have firstname and surname properties, some have middlename properties.  I'm looking for nodes that might represent the same person, so am looking at the different permutations of names.  I'm currently comparing surnames and the first initial of firstnames [ some nodes just have initials ], but can't figure out how to test middlenames if they exist.

My current query is:

```
match (a:Author), (b:Author)
where
  a.surname=b.surname and
  ( a.firstname starts with 'A' and b.firstname starts with 'A')
return distinct a,b
```

My understanding is that OPTIONAL MATCH refers only to patterns, so that won't work. I can't find a way to write an if statement that makes sense.

It may be that it makes more sense for me to do this programmatically, rather than relying just on direct Cypher queries, but I was hoping to keep it really simple and just do it in Cypher.

Some examples to clarify what I want to do.

Example 1:

```
 Node 1:  firstname "John" middlename "Patrick" lastname "Smith" 
    Node 2: firstname "J" middlename "P" lastname "Smith" 
    Node 3: firstname "J" middlename "Q" lastname "Smith" 
    Node 4: firstname "J" lastname "Smith"
```

I want a query that will return nodes 1, 2, and 4 as 'matching'.

Example 2:

```
Node 1:  firstname "Jane" lastname "Smith" 
Node 2: firstname "J" middlename "P" lastname "Smith" 
Node 3: firstname "J" middlename "Q" lastname "Smith" 
Node 4: firstname "J" lastname "Smith"
```

Here, I want all 4 nodes, since the 'canonical' name doesn't have a middle name.

Comment: You might want to more clearly elucidate what it is you're trying to do since "can't figure out how to test middle names if they exist" resulted in me telling you to use `EXISTS` and get down-voted for it.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully my expanded examples clarify better. FWIW, I didn't downvote you.  To me, your comment was a sign that I didn't clearly explain the problem I was trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like the following:

```
match (a:Author), (b:Author)
where
  id(a) < id(b) and
  ( a.surname=b.surname) and
  ( a.firstname starts with 'A' and b.firstname starts with 'A') and
  ( a.middlename=b.middlename OR a.middlename IS NULL OR b.middlename IS NULL)
return a,b
```

[How to work with null](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#cypher-working-with-null) is a good reference for puzzles like the one you're dealing with.

**EDIT:** Let's break it down with some pseudocode:

```
if (a.middlename is null) return true;
if (b.middlename is null) return true;
if (a.middlename is not null and b.middlename is not null and a.middlename!=b.middlename) return false;
if (a.middlename is not null and b.middlename is not null and a.middlename=b.middlename) return true;
```

Comment: Is there a reason behind that claim? I can't test it myself at the moment.

Comment: From what I understand of the somewhat incomprehensible requirements, the OP wants to compare people who both have a middle-name and compare people who both don't have a middle-name. The last clause you added basically matches everybody unless they have the exact same middle-name (weird?) or if one of them is nil.

Comment: You can do that if that matches up with the OP's vague requirements.

Comment: @joslinm is right, this isn't sound logic. `a.middlename=b.middlename OR a.middlename IS NULL OR b.middlename IS NULL` will return `true` if either `a.middlename` is null or `b.middlename` is null or if they're exactly equal, which contradicts the pseudocode example.

Comment: I wonder which of the pseudocode's ifs does that logic contradict?

Comment: On second thought I think I'm wrong here. My answer does the same thing except I don't make as many comparisons. Apologies! I've deleted my answer. You can improve your answer simply by adding `id(a) < id(b)` in your `WHERE` clause so you don't make duplicate comparisons.

Comment: That's ok, you guys had me questioning myself for a while there! ;) Thanks, i'll make that change.

Comment: This actually is more or less what I'm looking for.  If one of them doesn't have a middle name, but the other stuff matches, I want to save it.  See my added examples above.